# New pages ignore ruby code - Rhomobile

Tags: erb, rhomobile

In my Rhomobile project I just created a new .erb file in /app . But the commands between <%= %> are just ignored... In example, I have a link like this:

```
'href="<%= url_for :controller => :Settings, :action => :do_sync %>"'
```

but when I click it, nothing happens. How do I create new page files in which I can include such commands? May I map it in some config file?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the location of your `.erb` file and not your use of `url_for`.

Assuming that you refer to an action in your Settings controller, the `.erb` file should be located in `/app/Settings`. This means that if you want to render an action called `login` from your Settings controller, you would have to create the file `login.erb` so it is located at `/app/Settings/login.erb`.

In your `rhoconfig.txt` you can define the application start and settings path, if you want to change it so you start your application in a specific controller instead of in `/app/index.erb`.